# Rsync - preserving user, group, and permissions without su or being logged in as the user?

Tags: permissions, rsync

I need to automate (via script) rsync to send some files to a remote host for processing. However the user, group, and file permissions must persist across hosts for the processing to occur.

Due to automating this, password input isn't possible - the ssh key for the user performing the rsync has to already exist. The file's owner is root, so running the script as the owner (and therefore storing a root ssh key) is not possible. Because of this, it's also not possible to run this as a superuser.

Furthermore, the permissions of the file are 440 (root:groupImNotIn).

To top it off, modifying either host (can't turn on xattrs, use setgid, change any umasks, etc.) is not in the question, as both systems are in production.

Is there any possible way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

Found a method to achieve this: adding the receiving user to `/etc/sudoers` with `<user> ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync` to enable passwordless `sudo rsync` on the receiving end. This therefore retains all permissions/owners/groups on transmitted file. The rsync command used is:

```
rsync -aviL <file> <user>@<destination>:<directory> --rsync-path="sudo rsync"
```

With a saved SSH key for the transmitting user, all file transfer can be done automatically, without password input, or a root SSH connection being established.

However, this method does bring up the security issue of remote superuser rsync.